# Cannot get array key name

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the array `key` name of the following:

```
[tax_input] => Array
(
    [property-category] => Array
        (
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 8
        )

    [property-action] => Array
        (
            [1] => 9
        )
)
```

so I'm iterating it as:

```
foreach($tax_input as $key => $tax)
{
    var_dump($tax_input[$key]);
}
```

but this return an empty string, what I did wrong?

Comment: @vivek_23 fix typo, but still have the problem

Comment: Can you share minimum verifiable example? Use https://3v4l.org for demo sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get key only then use

```
foreach($tax_input as $key => $tax)
{
  var_dump($key);
}
```

Comment: @Badrinath generally it's good practice to use builtin functions if available.

Comment: Yes, but for @sfarzoso 's understanding this one is the best way.

Comment: `array_keys($array)`

Answer (score 1):

use php `array_keys()` function

```
print_r(array_keys($tax_input));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
foreach($tax_input as $k => $v)
{
    foreach( $v as $vk => $vv ){

      var_dump( '<pre>',$vv );
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just echo `$key` instead of `$tax_input[$key]`